# Can't seem to Import .glb / .gltf in svelte with vite

Tags: javascript, svelte, vite, gltf

I cant seem to get .glb or .gltf files imported.

```
<script>
    import HallucinateForm from "../components/HallucinateForm.svelte";
    import ModelViewer from "../components/ModelViewer.svelte";

    import tshirt from "./../assets/t-shirt.glb";

</script>

<main>
    <div class="eight columns">
        <ModelViewer model={tshirt}/>
    </div>
    <div class="four columns">
        <HallucinateForm />
    </div>
</main>

<style>
    
</style>
```

Gives me the following error.

```
    "message": "Cannot find module './../assets/t-shirt.glb' or its corresponding type declarations."
```

I've been looking around for answers and concluded that vite has no idea what to do with .glb. And i think needs instructions on what to do. Docs say that adding to the `vite-env.d.ts` should resolve the issue.

i have tried

```
declare module '*.glb'
declare module '**/*.glb'
// and tried 
export default defineConfig({
  assetsInclude: ['**/*.glb']
})
```

All without results. I think glb and gltf are unknown types for vite. [See](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/blob/main/packages/vite/src/node/constants.ts)

Most of the material i can find online is talking about Three.js and their GLTF-loader plugin but i'm using [google-modelviewer](https://modelviewer.dev/) . and can't seem to figure out if these will play together. I hope someone knows of a way to get this to work.

Comment: I assume you've found https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html#static-asset-handling ? I think using `assetsInclude` is along the right lines here. Another option would be to mark the "assets" as the public directory (described later on that page) and then write the URL explicitly rather than as an import.

Answer (score 6):

It depends on what you need from the import. If the model viewer expects a file path to the model file, this is fairly simple to do, otherwise you have to implement a plugin for loading the model differently.

For the file path approach to work, you just need to set the `assetsInclude` to `['**/*.glb']` as shown (in the Vite config) and add the type declaration which should look like this:

```js
declare module '*.glb' {
    const src: string
    export default src
}
```

This just states that in an `import model from './something.glb'` the type of `model` will be a `string` (the path to the static file).

The type declaration is only necessary for type checking via TypeScript.

---

If you do not mind changing the import statements, you can also use [explicit URL imports](https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html#explicit-url-imports), then nothing else needs to be changed. Just add `?url` to the import path; types for that should already be defined by Vite itself.

Comment: I've tried your answer but to no avail. Added the AssetsInclude back into the vite-env.d.ts. And i wasn't quite sure where to put the declare. Tried it in the script tag of the file where i was having issues with imports. It did resolve the import issue but gave a new problem where it told me module declaration was only allowed in .ts files.

After some searching i found out you can add index.d.ts to do the declare this didn't work either and setting ///<refrence path> for index.d.ts in the env.ts didn't work either returned the old error of vite not knowing how to handle GLTF.

Comment: You should have an `app.d.ts` file directly in the `src` folder that you can add that to, at least newer versions of the Svelte `create` script add that. `declare` should always be in `.d.ts` files.